# how to get this query right?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my 1st table

```
Type      LimitDays
-----------------
leave        15
absent       15
vacation     15
```

This is my 2nd table

```
Name      type      UseDays
---------------------------
Chuck     leave         3
```

now what I want is to join the two tables.. and display it like this..

```
Type       LimitDays    UseDays
--------------------------------
leave         15          3
absent        15          0
vacation      15          0
```

Here's what I've already done.. but

```
SELECT   
    Leave,
    Counter,
    (SELECT SUM(LeaveTbl.NumDays) AS Expr1
     FROM  LeavetypTbl 
     INNER JOIN LeaveTbl ON  LeavetypTbl.Leave = LeaveTbl.Leave
     GROUP BY LeavetypTbl.Leave, LeavetypTbl.Counter) AS Expr1
FROM     
    LeavetypTbl AS LeavetypTbl_1
```

the result is wrong..lol still can't it get right..the result looks like this

```
Type       LimitDays    UseDays
--------------------------------
leave         15          3
absent        15          3
vacation      15          3
```

Comment: Which [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) are you using?

Comment: im using MsSQL sir..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using MySQL:

```
SELECT LeavetypTbl.Leave, LeavetypTbl.Counter, IFNULL(SUM(LeaveTbl.NumDays), 0)
FROM LeavetypTbl LEFT JOIN LeaveTbl ON LeavetypTbl.Leave = LeaveTbl.Leave
GROUP BY LeavetypTbl.Leave
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer assumed that you are using SQL Server. Try using such query:

```
SELECT t1.Type, t1.LimitDays, COALESCE(t2.UseDays, 0) as UseDays
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.type = t2.type
```

There are 2 key parts. First is using of `LEFT JOIN`, because not all records exist in table2. Second, is to use `COALESCE` to display 0 instead of `NULL` if no values exist on right side of left join.

This works on your provided data, but you might need to use filtering or grouping if there are more records in either of the tables.

Comment: imma try that one out..tnx bud !